# flush not work after reset manager in doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

i have a error in my data and i get error `out of range on a integer column` and i try to prevent `closed entity manager` for proceeding work and for this purpose i `reset manager` in exception

```
public function renewDeliveryTime($delayReport) : void
{
    try {
        $this->delayReportRepository->updateRenewedDeliveryTimeAt($delayReport, 50000000);
    }catch (\Exception $exception){
        // out of range error
        $this->managerRegistry->resetManager();
    }

}

public function updateRenewedDeliveryTimeAt($delayReport,$delayDuration)
{
    /**
     * @var DelayReport $delayReport
     */
    $delayReport->setDelayDuration($delayDuration);
    $delayReport->setStatus(DelayReport::STATUS['DONE']);
    $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
}
```

the problem is after i have another object and almost same operation in database but seems `$this->getEntityManager()->flush()` not work any more and nothing happens in database . it is related to `$this->managerRegistry->resetManager()`

```
public function enqueue($delayReport) : void
{
    $this->pushInQueueReport($delayReport);
    $this->delayReportRepository->updateStatus($delayReport, DelayReport::STATUS['IN_QUEUE']);
}

public function updateStatus($delayReport, $status)
{
    /**
     * @var DelayReport $delayReport
     */
    $delayReport->setStatus($status);
    $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
}
```

what is the problem and solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `resetManager()` is, that not all services wich has a reference to the entitymanager directly will be magically updated to have the new instance.

In `updateStatus()` Method you can easy check if your entity is Managed by the entity manager.

```php
$uow = $this->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork();
if($uow->getEntityState($delayReport) !== UnitOfWork::STATE_MANAGED) {
    // not managed
}
```

Dont know if a reassign can help here like `$this->getEntityManager()->merge($delayReport)`.

**BUT its really better to avoid a closed manager and validate your data before.**

EDIT:

Not testet, if you will get the resetted EntityManager over the Registry. But its worth a try.

```php
$entityManager = $managerRegistry->getManagerForClass(get_class($delayReport));
```

Comment: my entity i managed by entity manager i added $this->getEntityManager()->persist($delayReport) i get another error A new entity was found through the relationship'App\Entity\DelayReport#order' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity:Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Order@547.To solve this issue:Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist()on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}).If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'App\Entity\Order#__toString()'to get a clue